# rake db:setup is failing for production because I am referencing a Model for a table that yet to be created in an initialier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to deploy my application on EngineYard. Right before `assets:precompile` it checks for database changes as part of the migration. This is causing a failure for me, because I am pre-loading some select box values as part of application startup:

```
STANDARD_ATTRIBUTES = {}
for standard in Standard.all
  begin
    STANDARD_ATTRIBUTES[standard.id] = {}
    valuehash = JSON.parse(IO.read(standard.json_file_name))
    for key,values in valuehash
      STANDARD_ATTRIBUTES[standard.id][key.to_sym] = values
    end
  rescue
    message = "Could not locate JSON file for the #{standard.name} standard. Perhaps you need to run 'bundle exec rake:monthly collect_unique_values_from_standard name='#{standard.name}'?"
    puts message
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.error message
  end
end
```

That first call to Standard.all is causing a problem, because the table has not yet been created. How can I get around this problem? There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416626/running-rake-assetsprecompile-fails-when-theres-no-tables-yet), but it's impenatrable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following condition around the whole block:

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(Standard.table_name)
```

I prefer to put this after the `end` of the block, in such a special situation.